# Where should I post my sum-up of the answers, as the OP?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, summary

Sometimes as the OP (question asker), after reading through all the answers, I have my own sum-up about them. I want to tell people and all further readers about my feeling and comprehension about my desired answer and how all the answers helped towards solving my problem.

Where's the correct place to put that information? Things I've considered:

- Edit into my question: No because that's not part of the question
- A comment under the question: I dislike that due to limited formatting in comments and its subject to removal (though the latter won't be the case)
- A comment under the highest-scored or the accepted answer: Still the same reason above. This is, for the time being, the place I'm posting that.
- A separate answer: Those thoughts probably don't qualify as an answer

Answer (score 6):

> A separate answer: Those thoughts probably don't qualify as an answer

Make them into an actual answer.  You seem to be describing a situation where no *one* answer is *the* correct one, but instead you combined several answers to reach a solution.  So you have a solution; you can share it.  When you repeat or adjust information from other answers, give them credit.  Make sure your answer stands on its own; you should write a complete answer, not "I took Alice's first suggestion and Bob's tangential idea and also did X".  Summarize or quote the parts of the other answers that you used.

I used this approach [in this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15687/472) and it was well-received by the community.

Answer (score 4):

If the overall text is helpful to other users in solving the problem if they find your question, it should definitely go in an answer. Such answers are not NAA as they do attempt to answer the question and are helpful to other users. They should not go into comments, as comments are intended to be ephemeral bits of information intended to clarify or ask follow-up questions.

If, on the other hand, you simply intend to provide feedback on the answers, and not help others solve the problem overall, that feedback should go in a comment on each answer.